# How can I force Chrome to open links with specific profile?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, multitasking

I'm using user profile switching in Chrome, which works perfectly fine. Except for when I'm clicking links, that are depending on one of the profiles being logged in. By default Chrome just opens the link in this profile, which was used last.

How can I force Chrome to use specific profile?

Answer (score 8):

With the current version of Chrome (51.0.2704.106 (64-bit)) you can just right-click an url and then open it with the fourth menu choice from top: "Open Link as `PROFILE`" (your configured Chrome profile).

---

EDIT: as pointed out by Daan Bakker, now (Version `108.0.5359.71 (Official Build) (x86_64)`) (I tried the Intel CPU build, but should work for arm M1 architecture as well) it's possibile to open the link in a different `PROFILE` when the target window profile it's already open.

Here two images by example. Menu when the target `PROFILE` it's already open:

[image: new profile]

Menu without the target `PROFILE` already open:

[image: no new profile]

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: not working any more :(

Comment: This does work, however, not when opening links from any other app, which is where I most often run into this annoying problem.
Furthermore, it would be great to have a default app and not need to remember and go through this menu process for each link.

Comment: For me "Open Link As" shows up but only when I already have another profile open in another Chrome.

Comment: Clarifying @DaanBakker's comment: you have windows from at least two different profiles open before this submenu is available. This feels like a bug to me.

Comment: @MichaelLiquori you can check out this app and it does what you ask for.

https://hikmetcancelik.com/open-in-profile

Comment: In 2023, at last, it works as expected: even if you only have your primary profile open, "Open Link As…" now lists other profiles. Only took 'em about a decade to make it work right.